# requiresConfirmation for One-Click Actions in Gmail

Tags: google-schemas

I'm trying to implement One-Click Actions for Gmail using a 'Confirm Action'. The [developer page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/one-click-action) specifies a 'requiresConfirmation' option `[if true, additional confirmation is required before the handler executes]`. I tried setting this to 'true', but didn't work.

How is this supposed to work? I'm using the following markup

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "description": "Verify your email address",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Verify Email Address",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://mywebsite.com/verify?email=info@mywebsite.com",
      "requiresConfirmation": true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The schema validates at [Schema Validator](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/testing-your-schema). Any help would be appreciated. The above code works otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requiresConfirmation` flag is not supported yet. I'll make sure the documentation is updated to reflect the current status.